# How can I write bytes to a file but break when the byte is equal to 0x00 or null?

Tags: c#

How can I write a byte array to a file but then break when the byte that is about to be written is equal to 0x00 or null?

I've tried to turn the bytes into a string and trim but that does not work.

```
                    message = new byte[4096];
                    clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
                    clientStream.Flush();

                    File.WriteAllText(AUTH_KEY"/email.txt",encoder.GetString(message).Trim());
```

Comment: Please  include some code. Will make it easier to understand what it is that you wish to achieve.

Comment: I added a small piece of code for a better understanding. I can not change the length of the read because I do not know what size the read will be.

Comment: Maybe you should look at the number of bytes read, which is returned by `Read`.

Comment: Sounds like a classic case of the xy problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: you need to write the bytes in the array up to the point where the byte value is 0x00,then stop writing to the file is that correct?

Comment: You will need to write each byte individually, checking prior to writing, if that byte is a 0x00. However, as @EvanTrimboli pointed out, you are probably asking advice on a bad solution instead of advice on the problem. Rethink what you are needing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Find the first index of 0x00 and then block write everything before it.

You can copy everything before the first 0x00 into a new array and then call

```
File.WriteAllBytes( string path, byte[] bytes)
```

Comment: Do you think it would be a bad idea to read the length of the buffer on client side and sending over the length and then trying to read it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you give a quick background?

Comment: well it depends, do you want to write everything before 0x00 to the file, or only write if there isn't a 0x00

Comment: He said "then break" so I think he always wants to write. *shrugs*

Comment: I'll explain properly. Basically I have a client and a server and I'm trying to send over a string but the size of this string can change so I just decided to make the read length to 4096 (4kb) but I only want the text that is useful to me not the empty bytes that did not get filled BUT this string can sometimes contain whitespace which I don't know if that'll be a problem.

Comment: But copying the array to a new one is unnecessary, just invoke a find() with an iterator get the index of the first 0x00 then do a for until that index

Comment: @MangO_O that's much slower. Writing to disk once takes far less time than writing to disk n times. You'd rather do the heavy work in memory.

Comment: Do you think I should just send the size of the string in byte format over first before actually reading the bytes?

Comment: @AidanMilligan Why don't you trim the string yourself? Once you find the index of the 0x00, backtrack until you don't hit any whitespace. That's your final index. Then cut off all whitespace chars at the beginning to get your start index (to copy into a new byte array). If you really want to, copy everything before the 0x00 to a new byte array, convert that to a string, and trim the whitespace.